# Rails 4 assets is not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, compass-sass

I have a Rails 4.2 project which is working fine. Recently I added one image and is working fine DEV ENV. But in PROD it is not working.

```
rails c -e production
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.6)
.bundle :001 > puts helper.asset_path("select.png")
helper.asset_path("select.png")
```

gives
      `/assets/select-76e7d10e7bc2f4f5c52248424f10ccbe24efd6384e0be58f2c9ad15f330abc9b.png`

If I simply tried `<%= image_tag("select.png") %>` in **application.html.erb** file, it works. But not in any **CSS** files. I tried all the below options

```
background: url('select.png');
background :url('<%= image_tag("select.png") %> ');
background: url('<%= asset_path("select.png") %>')
```

Nothing seems to be working

**Note:-** I am using compass-sass

Comment: Is the image inside `app/assets/images/`?

Comment: Test this: `background: asset-url("select.ng")`

Comment: Yes it is inside `app/assets/images/`

Comment: !!!!!.......asset-url("select.ng") worked. Could you please post it as an answer. I will accept it as right answer.